# Borrar espacios en blanco en mysql

Tags: php, mysql

tengo una tabla que contiene: nombre_completo, primero_nombre,segundo_nombre,apellido_paterno,apellido_materno.

Ahora bien estoy concatenando CONCAT(primer_nombre,segundo_nombre,apellido_paterno,apellido_materno) dentro de la columna nombre_completo.

Pero tengo el detalle que en la columna "segundo_nombre" tengo campos vacíos, entonces al concatenar los campos y aun así usando RTRIM, LTRIM o TRIM, me deja ese espacio.

Pongo ejemplo de como queda (AGUSTIN HERNANDEZ MARTINEZ) si se dan cuenta existe un espacio de más entre AGUSTIN y HERNANDEZ, ya que no tiene segundo nombre, pero no puedo eliminar ese espacio...

Esto es lo que he hecho hasta el momento para concatenar.

```
update participantes p SET nombre_completo = concat(p.primer_nombre,RTRIM(' '),TRIM(p.segundo_nombre),' ',p.apellido_paterno,' ',p.apellido_materno)
```

Espero me puedan ayudar

Comment: Pon lo que has intentado para que se te pueda ayudar

Comment: update participantes p SET nombre_completo = concat(p.primer_nombre,RTRIM(' '),TRIM(p.segundo_nombre),' ',p.apellido_paterno,' ',p.apellido_materno)

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y ponlo ahí

Comment: Ya lo coloque en mi pregunta

Comment: Prueba con `concat_ws(' ', p.primer_nombre,p.segundo_nombre,p.apellido_paterno,p.apellido_materno)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```
update participantes
set nombreCompleto = concat(primerNombre, if(length(segundoNombre) > 0, ' ', ''), segundodoNombre, ' ', primerApellidp, ' ', segundoApellido);
```

Lo que se hace aquí es usar un **if** para preguntar si el tamaño del **campo segundoNombre** es **0**, lo cual indica que está vacío, si es **0** entonces se concatenará a nada, de no ser **0** entonces se concatenará a un espacio, el resto de las concatenaciones se mantiene igual.

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias, me funcionó a la perfección